# Cannot connect to my Team Foundation Server outside my home network

Tags: tfs

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Remote access to Team Foundation Server 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6412549/remote-access-to-team-foundation-server-2010)

Me and a friend of mine is trying to connect to a team foundation server ive setup home.

Im using Win 7, Microsoft MySQL 2008 Express and VS2010 and VS Team Foundation.

When im at home I can connect my other computer (2) to my "laptop server(1)".
The problem is, when a friend of mine is trying to connect to my "laptop server(1) outside my home network he gets the error: "TF31002. Unable to connect to this network".

But if I move my laptop to his place and use his network, he can connect to me.

What could I do to fix this problem?

Best Regards Thomas

Answer (score 1):

You need to set your home router to forward the port you are using for TFS (8080?) from your external IP address to your PC hosting TFS.

Your friend needs to connect to your TFS server as if it were at your router's external IP address.